# Increment database value with update method in Sails/Waterline project

Tags: javascript, database, sails.js, waterline

I am working on a web application in Sails in which I manipulate the database with Waterline. Suppose I want to increment a field of a particular unit in the database like for example the viewsNo of a certain User, I currently do this:

```
User.findOne(userId, function foundUsr(err, user) {
  // ..handle error stuff..
  User.update(userId, {viewsNo: user.viewsNo + 1}, function (err, usr) {
    // ..rest of the code..
  })
});
```

Is it possible to handle those two database operations with a single call? Besides the database load it will also increase code clarity, but I was unable to find a solution.

Comment: As I am now locked to mongodb for this project I resolved this using User.native(function (err, collection) {}) in which I fired a native mongo query using $inc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes @Vee6 as you stated, using User.native() will work, another option is to do:

```
User.findOne(userId, function foundUsr(err, user) {
  user.viewsNo++;
  user.save(function(err) { /* updated user */ });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I catch your problem right the first query is needed just to check if record with given userId exist in database. In such situation you should probably add [beforeUpdate()](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#callbacks-on-update) method to your model.

Something like:

```
// api/models/user.js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {/* ... */},

    beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
         User.findOne(values.userId).exec(function(err, user) {
             // ..handle error stuff..
             if (err) return next(err);
             if (typeof user === 'undefined') return next(new Error('bad userId'));
             next();  
         });
    }
};
```

Now you can just update your values in controller and if error happens sails will stop updating.

**UPD:** About incrementing `viewsNo` in single query: no it is not possible at the moment. Here is [feature request](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/86) about it.

Comment: The first query exists in order to obtain the previous value of viewNo and the second query updates that number to be previous value + 1.

I would be in need of a User.update({viewNo: '+= 1'}, function () {...}) or something like this.

Comment: @Vee6 is seems that is not possible. updated my answer